# getting a list of properties and functions of any object

Tags: javascript

I'd like to iterate over the properties and functions of any kind of a javascript object(IDBKeyRange in this case).

I tried using the following code :-

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(IDBKeyRange.only(43));
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    document.write(arr[i]+"</br>");
    }
  </script>
```

However, it fails to show me a list of properties and methods -- what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems to work in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WMHyG/

Comment: Does IDBKeyRange.only(43) return an IDBKeyRange object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `for-in` loop:

```
for(var key in myObject){
    console.log(key, ':', myObject[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.getOwnPropertyNames returns an array of **keys**, the property names of the Object.

You have to loop through the Array and refer to the Object:

```
var O=// an object instance;
var A= Object.getOwnPropertyNames(O).map(function(itm){
    try{
        return itm+':'+O[itm];
    }
    catch(er){
        return itm+': ERROR!'+er.message;
    }
});

alert(A.join('\n'));
```

If any keys refer to objects you'll need a recursive method-

```
function deepProps(O){
    var arr= Object.getOwnPropertyNames(O).map(function(itm){
        var hoo= O[itm];
        try{
            if(hoo== window){
                return '\n'+itm+': window';
            }
            if(hoo){
                if(hoo.nodeName) return itm+': '+ hoo.nodeName;
                if(typeof O[itm]== 'object'){
                    return '\n\n'+itm+':\n'+deepProps(O[itm]);
                }
                return itm+': '+O[itm];
            }
            return itm+': null';
        }
        catch(er){
            return itm+': '+ 'ERROR! '+er.message;
        }
    })
    return arr.join('\n');
}
```